# Have any one implemented Vedic-mathematics in software before?

Tags: c#, .net

Have any one implemented Vedic-mathematics in software before? Vedic mathematics is incredibly beautiful and uses smart algorithms to do addition, subtraction, multiplication etc.

I'm trying to program this algorithms in C#.  I hope it will do the required operations in fast time and will solve the overflow problems.

I don't want to reinvent a library for bigINT or something like that, but I see that this kind of math is pretty smart and useful.  So if anybody has done something like this before please share what you done with me.

You can read on Vedic-math here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_math

Comment: Aren't the vedic math principles interesting rather for low-level processor implementation rather than for a high-level programming framework like .NET? I wouldn't wonder if many similar principles are already leveraged in modern processors.

Comment: Well, I can't say fro sure, but what are the principles behind these BigInt classes? I think they already implement O(nlogn) algorithms for multiplication and division, which is the asymptotic bound for these operations

Comment: I seems like Vedic math is really most useful for mental arithmetic in base 10.  If the Wikipedia article is a fair summary, it's neither complete nor computationally efficient.  Using base 10 will make it difficult to achieve good performance on most processors.  I also don't see how it handles overflow issues better than existing arbitrary precision libraries.  So I think an implementation would be most interesting as a pedagogical tool.

Comment: No, I think you are the first one to implement in C#.

Comment: use jquery a light weight library to do all thing

Answer (score 0):

First of all, vedic-maths is much advanced concept to apply for basic computation. It will not be a good idea to implement computation algorithms to do basic arithmetic operations using vedic-maths when it can already be done efficiently in binary. Again vedic-maths does not deal with anything other than base10. Again when it comes to doing basic arithmetic with vedic-maths there is a huge set of techniques that are applied based on operands which makes it insignificant to apply in computers.